# Would it be possible to generate aws provider blocks via terragrunt, based on a data "aws_organizations_organization" "all" {} call?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I have no idea if this would work, but I would like to use terragrunt to generate my providers blocks dynamically. Dynamic providers are currently not allowed (**https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19932)**.

I see this as a possible workaround.

Use a `data "aws_organizations_organization" "all" {}` to gather account info
Then use a loop with that data to do something like this

```
generate "provider" {
  path = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "aws" {
  for_each = data.aws_organizations_organization.all
  assume_role {
    role_arn = each.role_arn //#built dynamically of couse
  }
alias = each.account.data.aws_organizations_organization.all.[k].account_name

}
EOF
}
```

I just can't find any info on looping in terragrunt.

Comment: You could def do this with terragrunt.I am thinking of figuring out how. and pasting it as an answer.